# Create materialised view without data

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to create materialized view `test` without data then I will create a script to insert data into this materialized  view for the first time. After this I will run materialized view refresh to refresh the view every night.

As I am not expert in materialized views can anyone help me here.

At present I have script to create materialized view which is running for 2 hours for 20 million rows.

`create materialize view`

Comment: In Oracle docs, I've just come across this... "A complete refresh occurs when the materialized view is initially created when it is defined as `BUILD IMMEDIATE`, unless the materialized view [...] is defined as `BUILD DEFERRED`."

Answer (score 6):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to break up the MV creation into separate steps:

1. Create an empty table / materialized view.
2. Populate it.
3. Schedule a nightly refresh process.

For this you can use the `on prebuilt table` clause to change a normal table into a materialized view.

Demo source table:

```
create table demo_source (id, name) as
select 1, 'Red' from dual union all
select 2, 'Yellow' from dual union all
select 3, 'Orange' from dual union all
select 4, 'Blue' from dual;
```

New table which is going to be our MV (you could also populate it with the `create table as select`, or you could create it using explicit column names, datatypes, constraints, partitioning etc like any normal table):

```
create table demo_mv as
select * from demo_source s
where 1 = 2;
```

Populate it using a separate `insert` step:

```
insert into demo_mv
select * from demo_source;
```

Now we convert it from a regular table into an MV:

```
create materialized view demo_mv on prebuilt table
as
select * from demo_source;
```

Now `DEMO_MV` is a materialized view.

Comment: This.WHERE 1=2 is.a.really.smart.trick!  I use this all the time elsewhere but never thought to use it here.  I also agree with the need for a pre-built table because I have never encountered a big old mv that didn't need indexes, and the pre-built table ensures those are consistently generated (not forgotten).

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I'd create the materialized view "as is" (i.e. no restrictions you mentioned).

Anyway: the simplest option is to include the *false* condition in the WHERE clause which creates the object without data, such as

```
SQL> create materialized view mv_dept as
  2  select * from dept
  3  where 1 = 2;               --> this

Materialized view created.

SQL> select * from mv_dept;

no rows selected

SQL> desc mv_dept;
 Name                          Null?    Type
 ----------------------------- -------- --------------------
 DEPTNO                        NOT NULL NUMBER(2)
 DNAME                                  VARCHAR2(14)
 LOC                                    VARCHAR2(13)

SQL>
```

Comment: The problem is that the `1=2` condition is "baked in" to Oracle's definition of the materialised view. If you run `DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH` on this materialised view, you will never get any data in it. What the OP wants is to add the materliased view to Oracle with the correct definition, just don't populate it with data until his/her script refreshes it later.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked specifically about Oracle, but I got here looking for the same question about Postgres.

Luckily, Postgres has a 'WITH NO DATA' clause at the end of the materialized view statement that just creates the view but does not populate data into it. It can still be refreshed on-demand the same way after that.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creatematerializedview.html

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem. At deploy time I don't want that the refresh takes to0 much time. So here I think is a better solution.

```
drop materialized view test_mv;

create materialized view test_mv 
as select * from all_objects 
where 1 = ( select count(*) from user_tables where table_name = 'TEST_MV' )  ;

select * From test_mv
 => null 

exec DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('TEST_MV', method => 'C', atomic_refresh => FALSE, out_of_place => false , PARALLELISM => 4);
 
select * From test_mv
 => result is now of all objects
```